# Difference between listview and view.addView in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, view, comparison

Recently, I had take over some codes from another android developer and I realise that he is using a loop with view.addView to display a list of item instead of the android listview adapter. Is there any advantages of doing it in view.addView instead of the listview adapter? I also realise that the return result is rather slow. So I am wondering if it is because he uses addView that causes the slow performance.

Thanks to in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a big advantage for `listview` that it recycles each view when it is hiding/cant be seen from the screen(**example** scrolling the listview) vs `addView` which is constantly adding a view to the parent view without recycling it, thus having more memory consumption which causes lag/fps drops to the device specially to those with lesser heap size.

Comment: So it is recommended to use listview instead of addView, am I correct? 
And is there any advantages of using addView over listView?

Comment: @LeeYiHong if you want performance yes listview is way to go, addView is preferable when you have small amount of list data.

Comment: Ok noted. Thank you so much for your answer and fast response :)